# App crash in android lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to build an android app.
I've used headers in  the below code which is deprecated for 22 and I believe is the reason for crashing on lollipop.
I use header while calling `super.onsucess` for `Responsehandler` a subclass of `Jsonhttpresponsehandler` class.
I can't change the super method calling `Jsonhttpreponsehandler`.

```
 RestClient.post("change_account_status/", params,
            new ResponseHandler(ReferenceHolder.mainActivity, ReferenceHolder.PARTIAL_REFRESH) {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                                      JSONObject response) {
                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");

                        //TODO we should check here if the setting got saved on server
                        updateView(true);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Any suggestions to overcome this would be greatly helpful.
Android developers guide showed headers as deprecated in api 22.

Comment: Check if `response == null` before calling `response.getJSONObject("data");`. Also, please post your LogCat.

Comment: Thanks it is null, but it is not null while debugging on phones other than lollipop. Any possible reasons .Thank You